# Python script for extract test from log files

Tags: python

The problem statement as follows, There is log file contains logs related to testing results. For example it is contains text like testcase1 followed by logs for test case and testcase2 followed by logs for the test case and so on.

If user want to extract log for testcase1 and testcase3, script should read input from user like testcase1 and testcase3. Then extract only the logs for specified testcases.

In this case, assume user enter testcase1 and testcase3, output should be lines below the testcase1 and testcase3 from the log file.

Comment: Can you show some example logs? Your problem statement is too generic to allow for other to be helpful.

Comment: Please post the code which you implemented, we are not going to write the code for you. If you have any problem with your code, post the error here.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to go through an assumption that all the testcase logs are in separate lines, which means you are having '\n' after every log line.

Then you can read the files from linecache module.
Now again you should have your logs in a particular format. Here you have mentioned it as [testcaseN] [Log message] and [testcaseN] should have 'testcase' common with 'N' as variable.

So while you fetch all lines using linecache module, use re module for matching testcaseN given as input with the first word of individual lines fetched . Once you get a match, display the result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the woking script to extract the text

# Read particular line from the text file
     # For example in the program we are readin file and print only lines under the Title 2 and title 4
     # log file may contain empty lines as weel
     # Example log file
     # Title
     # 1
     # dklfjsdkl;
     # g
     # sdfzsdfsdf
     # sdfsdfsdf
     # dsfsdfsd
     # dfsdf
     #
     # title
     # 2
     #
     # dfdf
     # dfdf
     # dfdf
     # df
     # dfd
     # d
     #
     # title3
     # sdfdfd
     # dfdfd
     # dfd
     #
     # dfd
     #
     # title
     # 4
     # dfkdfkd
     # dfdkjmd
     # dfdkljm

```
in_list= []
while True:
    i = raw_input("Enter title to be extracted (or Enter to quit): ")
    in_list.append(i)
    if not i:
        break

    print("Your input:", i)
print("While loop has exited")
in_list.remove(i)
print "Input list", in_list

flist = []
with open("C:\\text.txt", 'r') as inp:
    #read the flie and storing into the list
    flist =inp.readlines()
    inp.close()

#making everything in the list to lower case
flist = map(lambda x:x.lower(),flist)
flist = [s.strip("\n") for s in flist]
print flist

    # printing the complete log file from the list. Since once we put the vlaue in the list the new line character will be \ appended in the list element.
    #hence striping with \n character
# for i in flist:
#     print i.strip("\\n")

for j in range(len(in_list)):
    result = any(in_list[j] in word for word in flist)
    if result:
        i_index = flist.index(in_list[j])
        flag = 0
        with open("C:\\output.txt",'a') as f1:
            f1.write(flist[i_index])
            f1.write("\n")

            while flag ==0:
                if "title" in flist[i_index+1]:
                    flag =1
                else:
                    i_index += 1
                    f1.write(flist[i_index])
                    f1.write("\n")
                    i_index += 1

f1.close()
```